# ClassNotFoundException when the class is generated by gen-class macro in clojure

Tags: clojure, clojure-java-interop, clojure-testing

I've namespace `myorg.helpers.fs-input-stream` -Its definition is

```clj
(ns myorg.helpers.fs-input-stream)
(gen-class
 :name "myorg.helpers.FsInputStream"
 :extends java.io.ByteArrayInputStream
 :implements [org.apache.hadoop.fs.Seekable org.apache.hadoop.fs.PositionedReadable]
 :main false
 :exposes {buf  {:get getBuf}
           pos  {:get getPos}
           mark {:get getMark}}
 :init-impl-ns false)
```

I've another namespace `myorg.plugin.orc-output` which uses the class generated by above namespace. Its definition is -

```clj
(ns myorg.plugin.orc-output
  (:import
   (myorg.helpers FsInputStream)
   (org.apache.hadoop.fs FileSystem FSDataInputStream)))

(set! *warn-on-reflection* true)


(defn input-stream-filesystem [buffered-bytes]
  (proxy [FileSystem] []
    (open [_]
      (FSDataInputStream. (FsInputStream. buffered-bytes)))))
```

Then I've test for namespace `myorg.plugin.orc-output` called `myorg.plugin.orc-output-test`. It has very basic test

```clj
(ns myorg.plugin.orc-output-test
  (:require [clojure.test :refer :all])
  (:require [myorg.plugin.orc-output :refer :all]))

(deftest orc-create
  (is (= 1 1)))
```

When I run the test in Intellij Idea I get error-

> Syntax error (ClassNotFoundException) compiling at (myorg/plugin/orc_output.clj:1:1).
> myorg.helpers.fs-input-stream.FsInputStream
>
> Full report at:
> /var/folders/b_/_t677thx43n6pd8l8x0c1qjr0000gp/T/clojure-13616919898936783952.edn

How can I fix this?

Note - The project is in [github](https://github.com/rajcspsg/gen-class-error-demo) as well.

Answer (score 1):

When using `gen-class` as a macro, as opposed to using it as a part of the `ns` form, you have to provide a `:name` that's a qualified name of the class that will be generated. So far, all good, except that you don't really have to use a string there - it can be a symbol as well: `:name myorg.helpers.FsInputStream`.

The class with the specified name will be generated in the specified package, so you have to import it as such. And that's where you've made a mistake: `[myorg.helpers.fs-input-stream FsInputStream]` should actually be `[myorg.helpers FsInputStream]` (I'd write it as `(myorg.helpers FsInputStream)`).

Comment: I applied your suggestion. Still I get the same error. I updated the question and github repo too.

Comment: There's no README in the repo and no mention of how you're preparing and running the project, but in order to make `gen-class` actually work you have to use AOT: https://clojure.org/reference/compilation